# Visualize the methodcalls in a java project

Tags: java, workflow, visualize

I'm currently working on a java-project, consisting of code I didn't write myself. Now I have to figure out how the code works.

So I was wondering if there are any programs/addons that show which methods are called over time, or that show the program in a visual way of which methods call what? Debugging would be a last resort because the code is huge, I want to get a global idea first before I dive into the debugger

Something like this (but then for Java) would be perfect :
http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html

Comment: try diver: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/diver-dynamic-interactive-views-reverse-engineering , it's a bit buggy, but has what you need... I don't know of any other tools doing this and I've looked everywhere.

Comment: Trying it out, and the documentation looks promising (the output), but all I get is an empty screen :(

Comment: the plugin is tricky... my guess is that it never made it out of beta and has been discontinued afterwards... maybe someone could revive it, because this plugin is actually a really great idea.